# Show Title/Date/Excerpt of first post & only Title for rest in Query

Tags: posts, wp-query, categories, formatting

I need to show 7 posts of a certain category.

The first needs to appear as Title / Date / Excerpt.

While the others can just be Titles of the posts.

Right now I am having trouble with getting the first post to appear different with my specific code.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

```
<?php $the_query = new WP_Query( 'showposts=7&cat=113' ); ?>
<?php while ($the_query -> have_posts()) : $the_query -> the_post(); ?>
<strong><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></strong>
<hr size="1" color="#919191">
<?php endwhile;?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your loop, you can use a variable to check, in this case `$i`, so the code will belong to:

```
  <?php $the_query = new WP_Query( 'showposts=7&cat=113' ); ?>
    <?php while ($the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
    <strong><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></strong>
    <hr size="1" color="#919191">
    <?php endwhile;?>


    <?php $the_query = new WP_Query( 'showposts=7&cat=113' ); ?>
    <?php $i = 0; while ($the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post();
    $i++;

    // First post
    if ( $i === 1 ) : ?>
        <strong><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></strong>
        <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
    <?php else : 
    // Other posts ?>
        <strong><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></strong>
        <hr size="1" color="#919191">
        <?php 
    endif;
    endwhile;
    ?>
```